# Facing issue when connecting with WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

I am creating below `custom binding`, `getting end point address from config` and then trying send request to WCF service.

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;

var endpointAddress = "";

ClientSection clientSection = (ClientSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/client");

for (int i = 0; i < clientSection.Endpoints.Count; i++)
{
  if (clientSection.Endpoints[i].Name == "HTTPS_Port")
     endpointAddress = clientSection.Endpoints[i].Address.AbsoluteUri;
}

EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(endpointAddress);
MyWCFService svc = new MyWCFService(binding, address);
```

I get following error

> The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected
>   'http'.\r\nParameter name: via"}

Answer (score 3):

you are not using security mode to transport. you need to add

```
    binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;



 According to definition =>  



//Security is provided using HTTPS. The service must be configured with SSL
    //     certificates. The SOAP message is protected as a whole using HTTPS. The service
    //     is authenticated by the client using the service’s SSL certificate. The client
    //     authentication is controlled through the System.ServiceModel.HttpTransportSecurity.ClientCredentialType.
```

Dont use

```
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
```

This security mode can be used only for http based client.

According to microsoft
 This mode does not provide message integrity and confidentiality. It provides

```
//     only HTTP-based client authentication. Use this mode with caution. It should
//     be used in environments where the transfer security is being provided by
//     other means (such as IPSec) and only client authentication is provided by
//     the Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) infrastructure.
```

Note: hosting this service needs SSL certificate.Please install this in IIS.

Comment: I am connecting to soap service shared by client. If i use 'Transport' with 'Https' do i need to mention certificate in my binding (config file)? OR this certificate has to be installed by client on IIS where they hosted this service?

Comment: Certificate is not specific to only wcf. you need to install it in hosted IIS machine.@simbada